# What is a "Pally"?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology

Frequently, playing the Scout in TF2, I hear this phrase:

> Thanks pally!

What does the pally in this sentence indicate?  Is it his imaginary friend?  A paladin?  Is it a nickname for something?

Comment: A random paladin in tf2 would be pretty awesome, but sadly it's just a colloquialism for "pal", aka friend, buddy, amigo, etc etc

Comment: @Chris Put a helmet on a Demoman and give him a sword.  Bam. Random Paladin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means pal, like friend or buddy. Like saying buddy instead of bud, you can say pally instead of pal (or at least the scout does). It is not a reference to paladins or anything else - it's just a scoutism.

Answer (score 9):

"[Pally](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pally)" is slang for "pal" which is another word for "friend."  It's somewhat archaic, in that it would have been more common in decades past.  It's fitting with the "New York"-esque aesthetic of the Scout's dialect.

It can also be used as an adverb to indicate being friendly, ie, "My neighbor and I were being pally by waving to each other while we were mowing the lawn"

Comment: Might be useful to note that it's older slang (1940-50s, if I'm reading correctly). It's the sort of thing you'd hear from the Rat Pack, for instance.

Comment: @AllenGould, indeed, it's certainly evocative of a particular regional dialect in a certain time period.  For some reason, I think of the northeastern US when I think of this word.

Answer (score 1):

It's slang for pal, commonly used in New England and New York dialects. It's basically just saying pal, with a little Scout flair.